# I'm trying to display data from Firestore into a MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, mpandroidchart

1. I'm trying to access data from Firestore db and display it into a MPAndroidChart.
2. The chart should display data from current week that match `parties` array. I'm not sure that I access the `weekdata` from my Measurement class.
3. The Measurement class uses `kotlin-parcelize` plugin.

[This is how data are stored in Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itOku.png)

Here is my code:

```
@file:Suppress("DEPRECATION", "UNREACHABLE_CODE")

class HomeFragment : BaseFragment() {

    private val pieChart: PieChart? = null
    val parties =
        arrayOf("Before Activity", "After Activity", "Before Treatment", "After Treatment")

    private val mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    fun getCurrentUserID(): String {

        val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

        var currentUserID = ""
        if (currentUser != null) {
            currentUserID = currentUser.uid
        }

        return currentUserID

    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

        return root
    }

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    private fun displayPieChart () {
        val pieChart = view?.findViewById<PieChart>(pie_chart)
        pieChart?.setUsePercentValues(true)
        pieChart?.description?.isEnabled = false
        pieChart?.setExtraOffsets(5f, 10f, 5f, 5f)
        pieChart?.dragDecelerationFrictionCoef = 0.95f
        pieChart?.centerText = "Weekly Pulse Analysis"
        pieChart?.isDrawHoleEnabled = true
        pieChart?.setHoleColor(Color.WHITE)
        pieChart?.setTransparentCircleColor(Color.WHITE)
        pieChart?.setTransparentCircleAlpha(110)
        pieChart?.holeRadius = 56f
        pieChart?.transparentCircleRadius = 61f
        pieChart?.setDrawCenterText(true)
        pieChart?.rotationAngle = 0f
        pieChart?.isRotationEnabled = true
        pieChart?.isHighlightPerTapEnabled = true
        pieChart?.animateY(1400, Easing.EaseInOutQuad)
        val l: Legend = pieChart!!.legend
        l.verticalAlignment = Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.TOP
        l.horizontalAlignment = Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.RIGHT
        l.orientation = Legend.LegendOrientation.VERTICAL
        l.setDrawInside(false)
        l.xEntrySpace = 7f
        l.textColor = Color.BLACK
        l.yEntrySpace = 0f
        l.yOffset = 0f
        pieChart.setEntryLabelColor(Color.WHITE)
        pieChart.setEntryLabelTextSize(12f)
        mFirestore.collection(Constants.MEASUREMENTS)
            .whereEqualTo(Constants.USER_ID, getCurrentUserID())
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { queryDocumentSnapshots ->
                val userdata : ArrayList<Measurements> = ArrayList()
                val weekdata = ArrayList<Measurements>()
                if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty) {
                    for (journals in queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        val displayData: Measurements = journals.toObject(Measurements::class.java)
                        userdata.add(displayData)
                        Log.d("Data for chart", displayData.activity)
                    }
                    if (userdata.size > 0) {
                        val dateStringArray = ArrayList<String>()
                        val c = Calendar.getInstance()
                        c[Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK] = Calendar.SUNDAY
                        val df: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy")
                        for (i in 0..6) {
                            dateStringArray.add(df.format(c.time))
                            c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
                            Log.d("Data ", dateStringArray.toString())
                        }
                        for (i in userdata.indices) {
                            if (dateStringArray[0].equals(
                                    userdata[i].date,
                                    ignoreCase = true
                                )
                            ) {
                                weekdata.add(userdata[i])

                            }
                            if (dateStringArray[1].equals(
                                    userdata[i].date,
                                    ignoreCase = true
                                )
                            ) {
                                weekdata.add(userdata[i])
                            }
                            if (dateStringArray[2].equals(
                                    userdata[i].date,
                                    ignoreCase = true
                                )
                            ) {
                                weekdata.add(userdata[i])
                            }
                            if (dateStringArray[3].equals(
                                    userdata[i].date,
                                    ignoreCase = true
                                )
                            ) {
                                weekdata.add(userdata[i])
                            }
                            if (dateStringArray[4].equals(
                                    userdata[i].date,
                                    ignoreCase = true
                                )
                            ) {
                                weekdata.add(userdata[i])
                            }
                            if (dateStringArray[5].equals(
                                    userdata[i].date,
                                    ignoreCase = true
                                )
                            ) {
                                weekdata.add(userdata[i])
                            }
                            if (dateStringArray[6].equals(
                                    userdata[i].date,
                                    ignoreCase = true
                                )
                            ) {
                                weekdata.add(userdata[i])
                            }
                        }
                        if (weekdata.size > 0) {
                            generateChart(weekdata)
                        }
                    }
                    pieChart.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                pieChart.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                Log.e(
                    activity?.javaClass?.simpleName,
                    "Error getting chart data.",
                    e
                )}
    }

    @SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForDrawables")
    fun generateChart(weekdata: ArrayList<Measurements>) {
        var beforeactivitycount = 0
        var afteractivitycount = 0
        var beforetratamentcount = 0
        var aftertratamentcount = 0
        var beforeactivitytotal = 0.0f
        var afteractivitytotal = 0.0f
        var beforetratamenttotal = 0.0f
        var aftertratamenttotal = 0.0f
        var beforeactivityval = 0.0f
        var afteractivityval = 0.0f
        var beforetratamentval = 0.0f
        var aftertratamentval = 0.0f
        for (i in weekdata.indices) {
            val displayData: Measurements = weekdata[i]
            Log.d("Data  activity", displayData.activity)
            if (displayData.activity.equals("Out of Bed", ignoreCase = true)
                || displayData.activity.equals("After Breakfast", ignoreCase = true)
                || displayData.activity.equals("Before lunch", ignoreCase = true)
                || displayData.activity.equals("Before gym", ignoreCase = true)
            ) {
                beforeactivitycount++
                beforeactivitytotal += displayData.pulse.toFloat()
            }
            if (displayData.activity.equals("Before Bed", ignoreCase = true)
                || displayData.activity.equals("After Breakfast", ignoreCase = true)
                || displayData.activity.equals("After lunch", ignoreCase = true)
                || displayData.activity.equals("After gym", ignoreCase = true)
            ) {
                afteractivitycount++
                afteractivitytotal += displayData.pulse.toFloat()
            }
            if (displayData.activity.equals("Before Treatment",  ignoreCase = true)) {
                beforetratamentcount++
                beforetratamenttotal += displayData.pulse.toFloat()
            }
            if (displayData.activity.equals("After Treatment", ignoreCase = true)) {
                aftertratamentcount++
                aftertratamenttotal += displayData.pulse.toFloat()
            }
        }
        beforeactivityval = beforeactivitytotal / beforeactivitycount
        afteractivityval = afteractivitytotal / afteractivitycount
        beforetratamentval = beforetratamenttotal / beforetratamentcount
        aftertratamentval = aftertratamenttotal / aftertratamentcount
        val entries = ArrayList<PieEntry>()
        entries.add(
            PieEntry(
                beforeactivityval,
                parties[0],
                //resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_star_24)
            )
        )
        entries.add(
            PieEntry(
                afteractivityval,
                parties[1],
                //resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_star_24)
            )
        )
        entries.add(
            PieEntry(
                beforetratamentval,
                parties[2],
                //resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_star_24)
            )
        )
        entries.add(
            PieEntry(
                aftertratamentval,
                parties[3],
                //resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_star_24)
            )
        )
        val dataSet = PieDataSet(entries, "")
        dataSet.setDrawIcons(false)
        dataSet.sliceSpace = 3f
        dataSet.iconsOffset = MPPointF(0f, 40f)
        dataSet.selectionShift = 5f
        val colors = ArrayList<Int>()
        colors.add(Color.parseColor("#40C9C0"))
        colors.add(Color.parseColor("#0699EF"))
        colors.add(Color.parseColor("#007DB8"))
        colors.add(Color.parseColor("#003452"))
        dataSet.colors = colors
        val data = PieData(dataSet)
        data.setValueFormatter(PercentFormatter())
        data.setValueTextSize(11f)
        data.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE)
        pieChart?.setNoDataTextColor(Color.RED)
        pieChart?.setData(data)
        pieChart?.highlightValues(null)
        pieChart?.setUsePercentValues(false)
        pieChart?.invalidate()
        (pieChart?.getRenderer() as PieChartRenderer).paintEntryLabels.color = Color.WHITE
        (pieChart!!.renderer as PieChartRenderer).paintEntryLabels.textSize = 35f
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
    }


    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.dashboard_menu, menu)
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        displayPieChart()
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        val id = item.itemId

        when(id) {
            R.id.action_settings -> {
                startActivity(Intent(activity, SettingsActivity::class.java))
                return true
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

And here is my *.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorOffWhite"
    tools:context=".ui.fragments.HomeFragment">

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
        android:id="@+id/pie_chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm new to Kotlin.

Comment: You have several different things in here and it's not clear what part you are asking questions about. If you are asking how to get the data from Firestore then focus on that part and omit all the chart details. If you are asking how to plot a given array of data on a chart, then remove all the firebase details and show a simple example with a pre-defined input array and describe what it is that you are having trouble with/want to do.

Answer (score 0):

[Tyler-v](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9473786/tyler-v)  Understood, so I displayed raw data on a BarChart. Now, what I want to do is to change that raw data for values that are in my DB.
Here is how the code looks:

```
 override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        val view =
            inflater.inflate(com.bloodpressurejournal.R.layout.fragment_charts, container, false)

        // val font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.activity!!.assets, "fonts/ProductSans.ttf")

        val bar = view?.findViewById<BarChart>(com.bloodpressurejournal.R.id.line_chart)

        val entries: MutableList<BarEntry> = ArrayList()
        entries.add(BarEntry(0f, 100f, "Before Activity"))
        entries.add(BarEntry(1f, 82f, "After Activity"))
        entries.add(BarEntry(2f, 95f, "Before Treatment"))
        entries.add(BarEntry(3f, 69f, "After Treatment"))


        val bSet = BarDataSet(entries, "Marks")
        bSet.setColors(*ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS)

        val barFactors: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
        barFactors.add("Before Activity")
        barFactors.add("After Activity")
        barFactors.add("Before Treatment")
        barFactors.add("After Treatment")


        val xAxis: XAxis? = bar?.getXAxis()
        xAxis?.granularity = 1f
        xAxis?.isGranularityEnabled = true
        val data = BarData(bSet)
        data.barWidth = 0.9f // set custom bar width

        data.setValueTextSize(12f)
        val description = Description()
        // description.setTextColor(R.color.colorPrimary)
        description.setText("All values in marks")
        bar?.setDescription(description)
        bar?.setData(data)
        bar?.setFitBars(true) // make the x-axis fit exactly all bars

        bar?.invalidate() // refresh

        bar?.getXAxis()!!.setValueFormatter(IndexAxisValueFormatter(barFactors))

        val l: Legend = bar!!.getLegend()
        l.formSize = 10f // set the size of the legend forms/shapes

        l.form = Legend.LegendForm.CIRCLE // set what type of form/shape should be used

        // l.typeface = font
        l.textSize = 12f
        l.textColor = Color.BLACK
        val lentries: MutableList<LegendEntry> = ArrayList()
        for (i in 0 until barFactors.size) {
            val entry = LegendEntry()
            entry.formColor = ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS[i]
            entry.label = barFactors[i]
            lentries.add(entry)
        }
        l.xEntrySpace = 5f // set the space between the legend entries on the x-axis

        l.yEntrySpace = 5f
        l.setCustom(lentries)

        return view;
}
```

Now, how to call the collection to add that data to the BarChart?

[image: barChart]